# React-Native Element type is invalid when converting IOS to Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am just learning about React-Native, so please provide some explanation in your answer.

I am trying to make this React-Native IOS example work on Android
https://www.raywenderlich.com/165140/react-native-tutorial-building-ios-android-apps-javascript

The example works great on IOS, so, I edited my index.android.js to use NavigatorAndroid instead NavigatorIOS like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import SearchPage from './SearchPage';

class PropertyFinder extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <NavigatorAndroid
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Property Finder',
          component: SearchPage,
        }}/>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', () => PropertyFinder);
```

I also added local.properties file in my android directory to locate android-sdk and that is for sure correct as I tried with other projects.

I have seen other posts on SO re this error but they were not providing answer in my case.

But running it on Android shows this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `NavigatorAndroid`. You should use `Navigator` instead. It works for both platforms. Check this: [Navigator documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/navigator.html)

Answer (score 1):

`react-native` doesn't export a component named `NavigatorAndroid` so you are getting `undefined` instead of a real component.

As you can read in the [`NavitagorIOS` documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#navigatorios) ...

> As the name implies, it is only available on iOS. Take a look at [React
>   Navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) for a cross-platform solution in JavaScript, or check out
>   either of these components for native solutions: [native-navigation](http://airbnb.io/native-navigation/),
>   [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

Comment: Thank you both, I'll investigate both suggestions.